# GoLang postgres testcontainers init script doesn't work

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, testcontainers

I want to start postgres container with init script.

```
request := testcontainers.ContainerRequest{
        Image:      "postgres:14.1-alpine",
        Entrypoint: nil,
        Env: map[string]string{
            "POSTGRES_DB":       "postgres",
            "PGUSER":            "postgres",
            "POSTGRES_PASSWORD": "postgres",
            //"PGDATA":            "postgres",
        },
        ExposedPorts: []string{"5432"},
        BindMounts: map[string]string{
            "/media/mihovelgod/Новый том1/GoProjects/microservices/sql/go-sql/resources/migrations": "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d",
        },
        Name:       "postgres",
        User:       "postgres",
        WaitingFor: wait.ForLog("database system is ready to accept connections"),
        AutoRemove: true,
    }
container, err = testcontainers.GenericContainer(
        test.CTX,
        testcontainers.GenericContainerRequest{
            ContainerRequest: request,
            Started:          true,
        },
    )
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicln(err)
    }
```

I got the following panic messages in log.Panicln(err):

```
failed to create container
Error response from daemon
invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

The point is that it perfectly works from docker-compose.yml.
How to fix this?

Comment: add slash at the end: `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`

Comment: @serge-v didn't help, got the same panic messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-go/blob/6b770200a5f777816d99189472166ccda72f47da/docker.go#L745), it appears that TestContainers wants `container_path: host_path` in `BindMounts`. What happens if you try:

```
        BindMounts: map[string]string{
             "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d": "/media/mihovelgod/Новый том1/GoProjects/microservices/sql/go-sql/resources/migrations",
        },
```

It looks like more recent versions of TestContainers have removed `BindMounts` completely and replaced it with a more generic `Mounts` field.